# SfDataGrid GroupStyle equivalent to DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, syncfusion

I'm currently porting my current `DataGrid` to the Syncfusion data grid `SfDataGrid`. but I can't find the opposite property to `DataGrid.GroupStyle` so I can manipulate this code with `SfDataGrid` control:

```
          <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Foreground="Black"  BorderBrush="#FF002255"  BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <DockPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                    </DockPanel>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <Expander.Content>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                </Expander.Content>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed, 
You can customizing the Group style of “**CaptionSummaryRowControl**” in SfDataGrid. For your reference, you have shared the documentation link as below. Could you please refer to it.

https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/styles-and-templates#styling-captionsummary

If you want to customize the **GroupSummary** of cells and rows in SfDataGrid, you can make use of below link,
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/styles-and-templates#styling-groupsummary

If you want to customize the **TableSummary** of cells and rows in SfDataGrid, you can make use of below link,
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/styles-and-templates#styling-tablesummary

And also you can customize the **GroupDropArea** of SfDataGrid, you can make use of below link,

https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/styles-and-templates#styling-groupdroparea

https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/grouping#groupdroparea-height-and-appearance